# Why can't C++ compiler infer template parameters?

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following example:

```
template<typename TI>
char trunc(TI IN){
        return (char)IN;
}

template <typename TO, typename TI>
TO applyf(TO (OP)(TI), TI IN){
        return OP(IN);
}

template <typename TO, typename TI,
          TO (OP)(TI)>
TO applyt(TI IN){
        return OP(IN);
}

int main(){
        int i = -21;
        char r1 = applyf(trunc<int>, i);
        char r2 = applyt<char, int, trunc>(i);
        char r3 = applyt<trunc>(i);
}
```

When I compile this code in g++ (with C++11), I get the errors:

> Function.cpp:21:12: error: no matching function for call to 'applyt'
>
> ```
>    char r3 = applyt<trunc>(i);
> ```
>
> Function.cpp:13:4: note: candidate template ignored: invalid explicitly-specified argument for template parameter 'TO' TO applyt(TI IN){

So my question is simple: The input argument type is obvious - an int - and to me TO should be obvious.

Why can't TO and TI be inferred, but they can be inferred in r1?

Comment: The compiler says pretty explicitly you're trying to match `trunc` with `TO`. The template has three parameters, not one, and there's no way `OP` is going to be inferred from the function argument.

Comment: I'm not sure what's "obvious" about this, frankly.

Comment: where is type OP defined?

Comment: I see - so in order to be inferred, TI and TO would have to be the 2nd and 3rd template parameters, but they can't be because TI and TO have to be defined before OP.

Comment: FWIW, `template<auto(OP)(auto)>` *might* work in C++17. `template<auto OP>` would, but it's harder to actually extract the argument type from either of those, though another option is a forwarding reference for the arg and that being an error if whatever is supplied doesn't work.

Comment: @chris: With `template <auto OP>`, the type of `IN` would probably have to become something non-deduced (i.e. `OP` would appear left of a `::`), so nothing is ultimately gained.

Answer (score 4):

`trunc` is a function template, not a type, and so it cannot match `typename TO`.